# Turn Image into a Button Image: Remove borders

Tags: html, css, image, button

I have this link with the following css.

```
    <a href="step1.php">Buy Now</a>

    //css

    #buy a {
    background:transparent url(signup_bt.gif) repeat scroll 0 0;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    display:block;
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:bold;
    height:37px;
    line-height:38px;
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration:none;
    width:126px;
    }

#buy a:hover{
background:transparent url(signup_bt2.gif) repeat scroll left bottom;
}
```

I now need to change it to a submit button to be used in a form and to look exactly like before. I did this:

```
<input type="submit" value="Buy Now" />

#buy input{
color:#FFFFFF;
font-size:14px;
font-weight:bold;
height:37px;
line-height:38px;
text-align:center;
text-decoration:none;
width:126px;
background:transparent url(signup_bt.gif) repeat scroll 0 0;
display:block;
}

#buy input:hover{
background:transparent url(signup_bt2.gif) repeat scroll left bottom;
}
```

It nearly worked but, its got a horrible border around it and on hover the button goes into the page. How can I fix this?

How can I remove the border and how can I get the button to just swap images normally and not go into the page.

Thanks all

Answer (score 5, accepted):

to remove the border

```
border:0px;
```

Comment: I thought I tried that but it was actually border-style:none I was doing!

Answer (score 1):

I use border:none in my CSS. It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use `<input type="submit" src="signup_bt2.gif" />` ?

Comment: This will not create an image submit button. It will create a default submit button. For example, in Chrome and Firefox, it will create a standard button with the text "Submit" and "Submit Query", respectively.